# Append Caroufredsel js file to the <head>

Tags: caroufredsel

According to the Caroufredsel specification the caroufredsel needs to be included in the head of a page. Problem being is that I can't access the head of a page as I have to integrate the code in a content slot of a platform. Is there a way around this so I can either dynamically add the script to the  because the caroufredsel doesn't load for me if I include it directly in the content slot.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: What is the message you get when you load the script before the slider div (and are loading jQuery before)? <script src="jquery.carouFredSel.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Could you tell me what you've tried before or hive a demo / [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)